# Entity Framework: How can I Detect Changes made to an entity on another form?

Tags: entity-framework, bindinglist

Below is a PART of INVOICE class from our Project :

```
public abstract class Invoice
{
   public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
   public int Status { get; set; }
   public virtual ObservableCollection<OrderRequestStatus> OrderRequestStatuses { get; set; }
   public EnumType.Follow Follow {get; set; 
   public string FicheNo { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date_ { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DueDate_ { get; set; }
   public DateTime? ShipmentDateEstimated { get; set; }  
   public DateTime? ShipmentDate { get; set; } 
   public string DoCode { get; set; } 
   public int AccountId{ get; set; } 
   public virtual AccountLayer.Account Account { get; set; }
   public int? SourceIndex{ get; set; } 
   public int CurrencyTypeId { get; set; }
   public virtual CommonLayer.CurrencyType CurrencyType { get; set; } 
   public double CurrencyRate { get; set; }
   public CommonLayer.InvoicePricing Price { get; set; }
   public string GenExp1 { get; set; }
   public string GenExp2 { get; set; }
   public string GenExp3 { get; set; }
   public string GenExp4 { get; set; }
   public int? LogoInvoiceLogicalRef { get; set; }
   public CommonLayer.TableLog Added { get; set; }
   public CommonLayer.TableLog Edited { get; set; }
   public CommonLayer.TableLog Cancelled { get; set; }
   public virtual ObservableCollection<StoredProcedures.sp_OtherSalesandOffers> sp_OtherSalesandOffers { get; set; }

 public Invoice()
   {
       OrderRequestStatuses = new ObservableCollection<OrderRequestStatus>();
       sp_OtherSalesandOffers = new ObservableCollection<StoredProcedures.sp_OtherSalesandOffers>();
       Price = new CommonLayer.InvoicePricing();
       Added = new CommonLayer.TableLog();
       Edited = new CommonLayer.TableLog();
       Cancelled = new CommonLayer.TableLog();

   }
```

Related Context code is :

```
  public TaksimGroupContext()
        : base("Name=TaksimGroupContext")

    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
       this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }
```

We have two forms :
1- INVOICE
2- INVOICE DETAILS

Form 1 INVOICE form related code

```
 private void DataBind_grdInvoices()
    {
         (from a in base._Context.Invoices
          orderby a.Date_
          where a.Date_ > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3650);
          select a
              ).Load();

           grdInvoicess.DataSource = base._Context.Invoices.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
```

Form 2 INVOICE DETAILS :

The data is loaded with same logic as above

The problem is :

We load the INVOICE from.Then we select one invoice and open INVOICE DETAULS form , which contains the Invoice header (From Invoice class) and Invoice Details ( from Stline class)

When we make any changes to Invoice ( NOT THE DETAILS ) , for example we change the Account, and then we save the changes, these changes are not detected by the INVOICE form.

EDIT : More precisely these changes are nor detected ( which we also don't try ) neither reflected to the grid .

Where are we making the mistake, or which other method should we follow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to 'detect' the changes in the INVOICE form?

Comment: I dont :) Shouldn't it be automatic ? Because i bind it to BindingList ? Please see edit : Detected and reflected should be more accurate .

Comment: I understand the problem now.  It is expected to refresh automatically in the first form. Are you using Winforms for this?

Comment: Hi adrian yes i use winforms

Answer (score 0):

`base._Context.ObjectStateManager` keeps the changes that occur in a context, independent on the form they are edited in.

You can use base._Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry to get an ObjectStateEntry for your Invoice object, which hold its original and current values in the OriginalValues and CurrentValues properties.

You can get the names of the properties that changed using the GetModifiedProperties method

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework)

Comment: So, how can we detect changes made on another form to the same object ?

Comment: check my answer, I Updated it

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the update, is there a method , a setting with which the changed values are automatically reflected to other forms ?

Comment: do you mean in the User Interface?

Comment: Yes i mean like some chnage in poco classes or something  that will automatically fire events in cse of change in collection