# Code first track database changes

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I'm trying to track all changes of my database overriding the `SaveChanges()` method.
My problem is how to get old and new values:

```
var addedEntities = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).Select(x => x.Entity);
var modifiedEntities = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(x => x.Entity);
var deletedEntities = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).Select(x => x.Entity);

foreach (var added in addedEntities)
{
}

foreach (var modified in modifiedEntities)
{
}

foreach (var deleted in deletedEntities)
}
}
```

In those loops I have to retrieve the old and the new value of the entity changed. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I believe your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework

Comment: i closed this, thanks! I searched in the net but i didn't see this post, sorry