# MVC5 with Entity Framework Get Modified Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

During a save using a scaffolded MVC Controller I want to get the properties changed.

```
private myEntities db = new myEntities();

public ActionResult Edit()
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     tblQuote quote = db.Quotes
     .Include(a => a.Parts)
     .SingleOrDefault(x => x.QuoteID == 4);

     quote.Name = "NewName"

     db.Entry(quote).State = EntityState.Modified;

     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've attempted to use GetModifiedProperties from here [Getting all changes made to an object in the Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework)

```
var myObjectState=db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(quote);
```

But VS tells me db "Does not contain a definition for ObjectStateManager".  How do I get the changed fields from "quote"

Comment: Try using `var myObjectState = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry([object name])`. Let me know if it works.